# Contact Form 7. Указать в коде адрес для отправки данных из форм

Tags: wordpress, contact-form7

Необходимо настроить почтовый адрес (именно в коде), на который должны приходить данные из форм. Подскажите, пожалуйста, где в коде указывается адрес. Нашла:

```
   $.ajax( {
            type: 'POST',
            url: wpcf7.apiSettings.getRoute(
                '/contact-forms/' + wpcf7.getId( $form ) + '/feedback' ),
            data: formData,
            dataType: 'json',
            processData: false,
            contentType: false
        } ).done( function( data, status, xhr ) {
            ajaxSuccess( data, status, xhr, $form );
            $( '.ajax-loader', $form ).removeClass( 'is-active' );
        } ).fail( function( xhr, status, error ) {
            var $e = $( '<div class="ajax-error"></div>' ).text( error.message );
            $form.after( $e );
        } );
```

дальше не понимаю, где url формируется. Помогите, пожалуйста.

Comment: посмотрите вот эту структуру => data: formData

Comment: Здравствуйте! Спасибо Вам, что откликнулись. Мне очень жаль, но я не понимаю, где её смотреть (в том же файле, откуда я приводила код?) и что я должна в этой структуре увидеть (((  Дело в том, что я верстальщик, начинающий и в такого рода вещах разбираюсь ну очень слабо. Если Вас не затруднит, может, можно поподробнее?

Comment: посмотрите как и где формируется data ваш отрывок содержит этап (POST)когда вы данные отправляете

Comment: Не понятно зачем это вообще нужно, если данный параметр настраивается через админку для каждой формы, но пропустим эту прелюдию. Понятие "в коде" очень растяжимо, т.к. в указанном примере вставлен кусок кода из скрипта плагина. Т.е. вы решили модифицировать файлы плагина?

Comment: В данном конкретном случае через админку не настраивается, иначе я бы не спрашивала. Я решила спросить знающих людей, что делать в такой ситуации. Я понятия не имею, можно ли там что-то модифицировать, а если можно, то что?

Comment: В каком месте скрипта плагина формируется url для отправки информации на ящик? Простите, если вопрос некорректен.